# Calculate SHA-256 of a byte array

Tags: php

I have a string `$concate` in the following code. I calculated the byte array of the string as follows:

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($concate); $i++){
    $binary[] = ord($concate[$i]);
}
```

Now I want to calculate SHA-256 hash of the byte array, `$binary`, but I don't know how to do that. Would someone advise?

What i have to do is:-

1. Calculate the binary (using utf-8 encoding) of a string(example - "hello world").
2. Calculate SHA-256 of result of step 1.
3. Calculate hexadecimal of the output of step 2.

Comment: What do you mean by "hash of the array"?

Comment: [`hash('sha256', $concate);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) - the byte array is a red herring, PHP doesn't use them in the same way that other languages do. Just use the string.

Comment: My guess is that the conversion to an array is redundant - you just need the hash of `$concate`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The string itself is in binary format. So `hash('sha256', $concate)` will be enough for this. If you want the output to be binary, set the third parameter to true.

```
$hash = hash('sha256', $concate, true); // or
$hash = hex2bin(hash('sha256', $concate)); // provides same output as above
```

It'll binary string instead of hex string.

See [this example](http://codepad.org/06o3znUJ) for illustration.

Comment: This is outputting something like :- Y1ÊØ'.EÀã½Pt0±çÜSÚ¦¯zâóSV®ô0úÕ

Comment: @TheRealCoder yes. thats because its binary! NOT hex form

Comment: @TheRealCoder Just don't pass true to the hash function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Answer (score 0):

You can store binary data in a PHP-string. There is no need to convert it into a byte array. I think this is what you're looking for.

```
echo hash('sha256', $concate);
```